# How to implement Deserialize for a struct? (Serde and SerdeJSON)

Tags: json, rust, serde

Insert this into your cargo.toml file: `serde = "1.0.140"`

https://crates.io/crates/serde

I have a struct here:

```
use serde::de::{Deserialize};

pub struct Transaction {
    pub sender: String,
    pub receiver: String,
    pub amount: f64,
    pub signature: String, 
    pub status: &'static str,
    pub weight: u128,
    pub timestamp: Duration,
    pub edges: Vec<Transaction>,
}
```

I would like to implement the trait `Deserialize` for this struct, but I do not know how to do so properly.

Here is my attempt.

```
impl Deserialize for Transaction {
    fn deserialize<'de>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Transaction, D::Error>
    where 
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_struct("Transaction", 9, None)
    // I don't know what to assign as the `Visitor`
    }
}
```

But the implementation above is infested with errors. Here is the full log.

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'de`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:18
   |
13 | impl Deserialize<'de> for Transaction {
   |     -            ^^^ undeclared lifetime
   |     |
   |     help: consider introducing lifetime `'de` here: `<'de>`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `D`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:65
   |
14 |     fn deserialize<'de>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Transaction, D::Error>
   |                                                                 ^ use of undeclared type `D`

error[E0412]: cannot find type `D` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
   |         ^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `D` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:14:39
   |
14 |     fn deserialize<'de>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Transaction, D::Error>
   |                                       ^ not found in this scope

error[E0049]: method `deserialize` has 0 type parameters but its trait declaration has 1 type parameter
  --> src/lib.rs:14:20
   |
14 |     fn deserialize<'de>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Transaction, D::Error>
   |                    ^^^ found 0 type parameters, expected 1

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0049, E0261, E0412, E0433.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0049`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 5 previous errors
```

**How do I successfully implement this?**

Comment: `status: &'static str` indicates that `status` can only take a limited amount of values that are known at compile time. Would it be a possibility to refactor `status` to be an `enum` instead? That would make it much easier to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really unique use case (you need a data format which where isn't already a serde crate for), you don't need to implement the entire trait yourself, you can instead derive a default implementation of `Deserialize` (and/or `Serialize`) on your struct:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Transaction {
    pub sender: String,
    pub receiver: String,
    pub amount: f64,
    pub signature: String, 
    pub status: &'static str,
    pub weight: u128,
    pub timestamp: std::time::Duration,
    pub edges: Vec<Transaction>,
}
```

This handles everything for you behind the scenes, but you need to enable the `derive` feature flag for `serde` in your `Cargo.toml`.

And then to actually *use* the serialization/deserialization, use a crate like `serde_json`, `serde_yaml`, etc depending on which format you need.

Comment: The lifetime of `status` is going to be a problem; good luck actually deserializing this without running into a compile-time error. Basically you'll only be able to deserialize from `&'static str` which is probably not what OP wants. This should probably be a `String` field like the others, or it should have a custom deserializer (`#[serde(deserialize_with = "...")]`).

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Does it handle it specially at all because of `'static`?

Comment: There is no "special handling" per se, the deserialized input just has to outlive the longest lifetime in the struct. Since that's `'static`, you'll only be able to deserialize from `&'static str`, which is almost certainly way too restrictive. For example, if you try to deserialize from a `String` you [get an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef0b7434cf919c3a1a96b742498d4f8a).